# Send last message over socket before exiting app

Tags: android, sockets, ondestroy

I have 16 clients connected to a server (2 different app projects) over sockets in Android. If a new client connects, the server keeps track of it.
When a client closes the app, the server should be notified that 1 client has disconnected. The problem is that I only catch the event sometimes and sometimes the app closes too fast for the message to be sent.

What is the best practice of achieving something like that? This application is only for an internal project so the solution doesn't have to be the most beautiful piece of code as long as it works.

This is my `onDestroy()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (isConnected) {
        sendMessageToServer("ByeBye from " + MainActivity.mPreferences.getString("deviceID", "EMPTY_ID"));
    }

    if (localClient.getClientSocket() != null) {
        if (localClient.getClientSocket().isConnected()) {
            try {
                localClient.getClientSocket().close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    localClient.shutdown();

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Comment: Whether or not your clients are able to send a final message to the server before disconnecting, the server should always be able to detect disconnects regardless of whether those final messages are received.  If it is not doing that correctly, then it has a bug that needs to be fixed.  And why is your project calling `killProcess()` on itself?  It should not be doing that at all.

Comment: How would I do that? I don't know how I can detect if the connection was closed. I'm using that so that all sockets are closed for sure and if the app is reopened everything is fresh. I don't want to "Force Close" the app on 16 phones everytime.

Comment: On the server side, when a client disconnects, any further I/O on the `Socket` for that client should fail. Are you handling that condition? Doesn't sound like it. For instance, `InputStream.read()` will return -1 if the connection is closed gracefully, and throw an `IOException` otherwise. Use those indicators to close the `Socket` and remove that client from your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnDestroy() on Activities and Services isn't guaranteed to be called so you can't rely on that to send an explicit 'bye' to your server which signals the server to close down that connection.

Since clients can and will behave unexpectedly (loss of connectivity, app crashes etc.), then the responsibility should be on the server to manage and track connection state.   If you have some kind of ping or keep-alive between client and server that you send regularly then you can rely on that to also track connection state.  If the server is unable to send that to the client or is not receiving it from the client for a certain amount of time, then the connection is likely dead and you can have the server consider the connection dead.

Answer (score 1):

Activity could be destroyed when Android needs some resources for other apps. At that moment your app could be restricted to use networking (because it is not on the foreground).

The best place is to send bye message in Activity::OnStop method when app still has access to the network